# forkJoin does not working properly with more calls?

Tags: angular, typescript

I put two methods in forkJoin but it's does not call api if I put a both, it does not return anything from backend api, but If I throw some of them from forkJoin everything works good. I got error when I have two calls in forkJoin. This is piece of code:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe
      (
        paramMap => {
          this.inviteToken = paramMap.get('inviteToken');
        });

    forkJoin([
      this.inviteService.getClientTheme(this.inviteToken),
      this.inviteService.getUserAuthenticationProfiles(this.inviteToken)]
    ).subscribe(([clientTheme, authenticationProfiles]) => {
      this.clientTheme = clientTheme;
      this.localStorage.setClientTheme(this.clientTheme);
      this.authenticationProfiles = authenticationProfiles;
    },
      errorMessage => {
        this.error = errorMessage;
      },
      () => {
        this.spinner.hide();
      }
    );
  }
```

invite.service.ts

```
getClientTheme(inviteToken: string): Observable<IClientTheme> {
    const reqUrl = 'clients/invites';
    this.url = `${this.url}${reqUrl}/${inviteToken}`;

    return this.get()
        .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError));
}

getUserAuthenticationProfiles(inviteToken: string): Observable<any> {
    const reqUrl = 'consumers';
    this.url = `${this.url}${reqUrl}/${inviteToken}`;

    return this.get()
        .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError));
}
```

Comment: Well you are assigning the inviteToken asynhronously that is most probably why you are not getting the expected results from BE as the token would be undefined.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu You mean on this part:       this.route.paramMap.subscribe
      (
        paramMap => {
          this.inviteToken = paramMap.get('inviteToken');
        });  ?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: Yaeh, I've changed it to  this.inviteToken = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('inviteToken'); but the same issue..